# Why is meson interpreting my ccflags with the single quotes?

Tags: gcc, meson-build

I'm editing a meson build file. a line that currently exists the the file is working perfectly.

```
if cc.has_argument('-Wno-format-truncation')                                                                                                                                                                                           
default_cflags += '-Wno-format-truncation'
endif
```

I've added a line because I want debug information:

```
default_cflags += '-ggdb -O0'
```

However, this is being interpreted *with* the single quotes, and breaking the make command.

```
-Wno-missing-field-initializers -D_GNU_SOURCE -march=native '-ggdb -O0' -DALLOW_EXPERIMENTAL_API -MD -MQ
```

Obviously, `cc` doesn't like this and is throwing an error. What is causing meson to interpret this output *with* the single quotes? I've tried double quotes and no quotes, but that throws other errors altogether.

## Edit

This is a dpdk build file, so the compiler call is:

```
            executable('dpdk-' + name, sources,
                    include_directories: includes,
                    link_whole: link_whole_libs,
                    link_args: ldflags,
                    c_args: default_cflags,
                    dependencies: dep_objs)
```

Comment: How are you passing `default_cflags` to your target??

Comment: @BrydonGibson is your goal to build the binary with `-O0 -g` for debugging with meson? If yes, there is much easier way than modifying or editing the meson file. Please let me know.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Exactly. The accepted answer provides a way to do that. I am new to meson so I'm generally used to adding my own targets and such to makefiles

Comment: @BrydonGibson thanks for confirming I have only modified pmod answer to reflect your intention. Happy to hear your problem is resolved.

Comment: @VipinVarghese thank you for updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **+=** syntax is used by meson to add elements to arrays (append). Thus, when array is later flattened and space is detected - then quotes are used, I guess. So append one by one:

```
default_cflags += '-ggdb'
default_cflags += '-O0'
```

or update as array:

```
default_cflags += ['-ggdb, '-O0']
```

As for the debug information, check meson's **[core options](https://mesonbuild.com/Builtin-options.html#core-options)**: **buildtype** and **optimization**. You can configure your build without including related flags into meson.build (if it suffices to your needs).

The option to use is `--buildtype=debug` for non optimized binary and `--buildtype=debugoptimized` for binary built with `-g -O2`.

The recommended way to pass these CFLAGS arguments as list objects. Such for `shared_library, static_library, executable` with the custom `c_args : default_cflags` where default_cflags is declared as

```
default_cflags = []
...
...
...
if is_debug
  default_cflags += ['-ggdb', '-O0']
endif
...
...
```